# Creating dynamic child context menu based on AJAX call

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension where I need to create dynamic sub-contextMenus based on some selected text. Like If you select a text, it'll send an ajaxrequest from the background.html and create some child context menu based on the returned results. Is that possible? I've been trying for sometime. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add right mouse button event listener in a content script:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
        if(event.button == 2) {
                //get selected text and send request to bkgd page to create menu
        }
}, true);
```

There is also `oncontextmenu` event, can try it as well (I think `mousedown` is fired earlier though).